# Returning array from recursive method

Tags: java

Hello i hope you are all good.
I have this method i want to look recursively on a folder to count files and files that accept the condition and i want to return them as a array.
I am having trouble on count+=countThem(file); , how can i fix it that that it can increase boll variables (count for files) and (countkusht for files that accept the condition)

```
  public int[] countThem(File f,String parameter) throws IOException {
            int count = 0;
            int countkusht = 0;
            File[] files = f.listFiles();
            for (File file : files) {
                   if(file.isDirectory()) {
                //->   **count+=countThem(file);**
                       }
                   else if(!file.isDirectory()) {
                                count++;
                       fr = new FileReader(file);
                       br = new BufferedReader(fr);

                       String line = null;

                       while((line = br.readLine())!=null) {
                            if(line.contains(parameter)) {
                                 countkusht++;
                            }
                       }       
                   }
            }

            return new int[] {count,countkusht};

        }
```

Comment: count is an int, countThem returns an array of int. Java does not support such action of adding an int array to an int

Comment: hmm for returning one result like just count files it is working perfectly fine . so you are saying that i cant return 2 variables using array in this case?

Comment: Also, at the same line, you are calling `countThem(file)` with only one parameter, yet the function actually requires two: File and String

Comment: yeah i know it was a typing mistake but thats not the point , my point is how to return both variables count and countkusht

Comment: You can return whatever you want, but you can't add whatever you want to an int. You can only add an int to an int.

Comment: And how can i fix it that ,so it will increase both count and countKusht ( line 7)

Comment: The answer below provides a good solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to index the array results of countThem

```
               if(file.isDirectory()) {
                 int[] ct = countThem(file, parameter);
                 count+=ct[0]
                 countkusht+=ct[1];
               }
```